# How can I create an href condition in this vuejs example?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So in the example below - gitHublink returns a url for a repository.  The problem is N/A has an href link to N/A.

in template:

```
<td :style=tdStyle v-if="githubLink === 'N/A'"> no url found </td>
<template :v-else>
<td :style=tdStyle><a v-bind:href="[[ githubLink ]]">[[ githubLink ]]</a></td>
</template>
```

computed method:

```
  githubLink() {
    returnVar = 'N/A'
    this.job.forEach(obj =>
        obj.env_vars.forEach(var_set => {
            if (var_set.name.name == 'url') {
                returnVar = 'https://github.corp.test.com/'+var_set.value.value
            }
        }
    ))
    return returnVar;
  },
```

How do I make it so there is no href link if there is no url found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If am understanding your question right, you would like to display `No url found`, if the github link is `null` or `undefined` (in your case you are setting the default to **N/A**) else display the link `a`.

To do so, what you may do is **Conditional rendering** using [`v-else`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else)

As seen in the docs you may define your template with `v-if` and `v-else`. (ie) use v-if to check if githublink equals `N/A` to display no url found, something along the lines of

```
<td :style=tdStyle>
  <div v-if="githublink === 'N/A'"> no url found />
  <div v-else>
    <a :href="githubLink">{{githubLink}}</a></td>
  </div>
</td>
```

Also additional unsolicited tip, you may also want to check if `var_set.value` exists in your if condition. *It could be possible that your data is well defined and that if `url` is present, possibly value is also available, but better to be safe*

**Edit - based on the o/ps's comment/need to use a template**
So if you were to use a template, it would look like the following, however remember a `template` is used to wrap more than one element based on `if-else` as seen in the docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt), meaning one can toggle more than an element.

```
 <template  v-if="githublink === 'N/A'">
   <td :style=tdStyle> <strong> no url found </strong> </td>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
     <td :style=tdStyle> 
        <a :href="githubLink">{{githubLink}}</a>
     </td>
   </template>
```

Comment: Can I use this example but replace div with template?

Comment: I have updated the OP with an example of what I am trying to do

Comment: Sure you can, but remember One uses a `template` only if you have more than one element to toggle. So what are those elements you want to toggle (show or not show) based on the condition ? Read the doc link carefully to know the use case to use a template

Comment: I have been using template because when I use div it affects the spacing of other divs

Comment: that's because you wrapped it up wrongly. Always ensure you read the docs carefully, and also  a request do not keep editing your question based on the answers posted cause it doesnt help anyone else having a similar issue if the flow is lost, keep adding more information to your question , like state, "i tried this " and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I believe a v-if / v-else solves your problem

```
<td :style="tdStyle">
    <a v-if="githubLink !== 'N/A'" :href="githubLink">{{ githubLink }}</a>
    <span v-else>N/A</span>
</td>
```